# Angular2 - Back button inside multiple named router outlet

Tags: angular, button, back

I have 2 named router outlets, and they have their own back button. When a user clicks the back button, it should get him back in that router, but instead, it just returns him to previous location no matter the router outlet.
Here is code.

```
<router-outlet name="out1"></router>
<router-outlet name="out2"><router>
```

TS

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

goBack() {
this.location.back();

}
```

Any way for this back button functionality, to return user to a previous state only for  that outlet where back button is placed?

Comment: `.back()` navigates to previous location. In this case you should use router's `navigate` or `navigateByUrl` methods.

Comment: @Haseoh But then I have to define for every page where it will route?